# Bind DataGrid to Model Collection via ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm new to Caliburn.Micro, but have done some basic WPF MVVM programming so aware of the concepts. I tend to develop in a Model first style and so having an issue binding a WPF `DataGrid` to a collection defined and updated in the `Model`. How best should I expose a reference to the `Collection` via the `ViewModel` to the `View`, so that any updates in the `Model` are propagated via the `ViewModel` reference, rather than having to wire up in the `ViewModel`?

`Model`:

```
public class Market : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _MarketGroup;
    public string MarketGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _MarketGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MarketGroup != value)
            {
                _MarketGroup = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MarketGroup);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Expiry;
    public string Expiry
    {
        get
        {
            return _Expiry;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Expiry != value)
            {
                _Expiry = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Expiry);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _MarketStatus;
    public string MarketStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _MarketStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MarketStatus != value)
            {
                _MarketStatus = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MarketStatus);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Epic;
    public string Epic
    {
        get
        {
            return _Epic;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Epic != value)
            {
                _Epic = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Epic);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _InstrumentName;
    public string InstrumentName
    {
        get
        {
            return _InstrumentName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_InstrumentName != value)
            {
                _InstrumentName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => InstrumentName);
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface IMarketService : InotifyPropertyChanged
{
    BindableCollection<Market> Markets {get;}
    void RefreshMarkets();
}

public class MarketService : PropertyChangedBase, IMarketService
{
    public MarketService()
    {
        Markets = new BindableCollection<IGMarket>();
    }

    private BindableCollection<Market> _Markets;
    public BindableCollection<Market> Markets
    {
        get
        {
            return _Markets;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (_Markets!= value)
            {
                _Markets = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Markets);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RefreshMarkets()
    {
        Markets.Clear();

        var markets = GetMarkets();

        foreach (var market in markets)
        {
            Markets.Add(market);
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private readonly IMarketService _MarketService;
    private readonly IAccountService _AccountService;

    public ShellViewModel(IMarketService marketService, IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _MarketService = marketService;
        _AccountService = accountService;

        Markets = new BindableCollection<IGMarket>(_MarketService.Markets);
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (_AccountService.Login())
            {
                LoggedIn = true;

                _MarketService.RefreshMarkets();
            }
        });
    }

    private BindableCollection<Market> _Markets;
    public BindableCollection<Market> Markets
    {
        get { return _Markets; }
        set
        {
            if (_Markets != value)
            {
                _Markets = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Markets);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`AccountService` and `MarketService` are both registered as singletons in the `AppBootsrapper` using Simple Injector as the DI framework.

`View`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="Markets" Margin="0,0,0,0" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Width="auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InstrumentName}" Header="Instrument Name" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Expiry}" Header="Expiry" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MarketGroup}" Header="Market Group" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InstrumentType}" Header="Instrument Type" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MarketStatus}" Header="Market Status" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Essentially nothing appears on the `Grid`, even though `_MarketService.Markets` contains items. I'd like to make the `View` and `ViewModel` respond to changes/updates to the `Model` `BindableCollection` if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a separate collection of `Markets`? The common design is to use

```
public BindableCollection<Market> Markets
{
    get { return _MarketService.Markets; }
    set
    {
        if (_MarketService.Markets != value)
        {
            _MarketService.Markets = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Markets);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now you have two separate collections, one in `ShellViewModel.Markets` and one in `ShellViewModel.MarketService.Markets`, and they are not referring to the same reference in memory or being synchronized in any way.

Comment: thanks Rachel. I'm sure i tried that earlier on and it was giving me a thread exception but this is working now!

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your `datagrid` on your `BindableCollection`

Try this in your xaml `ItemsSource={Binding Markets}`

Comment: thanks for your response. i was under the impression that for Caliburn.Micro, using convention 'x:Name="Markets"' would take care of the binding?

Comment: @percentum Yes, I think that is how Caliburn Micro works. It uses the `Name` property to create common bindings, so if a DataGrid is named Markets, it will create a binding for `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `{Binding Markets}`